# Error in starting cassandra in windows 10 PC

Tags: java, database, cassandra, jvm, java-16

I had downloaded the Cassandra software and installed the dependencies i.e. Python and Java. Then in cmd I wrote the following command.

```
C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.10\bin>cassandra
```

It gave the following output

```
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
   Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
   on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
   functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

My java version is:

```
C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.10\bin>java --version
java 16 2021-03-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16+36-2231)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16+36-2231, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Does Cassandra 3.11.10 support Java-16?

Comment: The Cassandra 3.11.10 doesn't support java 16. You can try downgrade to 8 or 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set the appropriate execution policy in Powershell.
2. Cassandra 3 only works with Java 8 and lower.

The other possibility for you is to run Cassandra on WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux).

Comment: Worth noting, I believe firmly that anyone who wants to run Cassandra on Windows enjoys causing pain for themselves.